# Show that one can write $\omega = \frac{i}{2\pi}\partial \bar{\partial} \varphi$ for some positive function $\varphi$ and determine $\varphi$.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\omega = \frac{i}{2\pi} \sum dz_i \wedge d\bar{z_i}$ be the standard fundamental form on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Show that one can write $$\omega = \frac{i}{2\pi}\partial \bar{\partial} \varphi$$ for some positive function $\varphi$ and determine $\varphi$.

---

So I have two questions one minor detail related to the fundamental form and one for the actual problem.

1. Why  is there $\pi$ in the denominator of the scaling factor for the sum? This doesn't seem to be the "standard" fundamental form.

For the actual problem I started this by just considering $\mathbb{C}^1$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^n$. In $\mathbb{C}^1$ we want to find a positive function $\varphi$ such that $$\omega = \frac{i}{2\pi}\partial \bar{\partial} \varphi = \frac{i}{2\pi}\partial \left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}} d \bar{z_1}\right) = \frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z_1} d\bar{z_1} \wedge dz_1 = -  \frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z_1} dz_1 \wedge  d\bar{z_1}  $$ so $\varphi$ should be a positive function such that $$\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z_1} = -1$$ in order for us to get this to equal the standard fundamental form. I'm confused about this $$\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z_1}$$ term since I do not know what it should represent in this complex case. Is this even something that is defined as the complex partial derivatives are usually defined in terms of the expansion $x+iy$. What can we do here?

Comment: By definition we simply have $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$, and hence $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\overline{z}\partial z} = \frac{1}{4}\Delta$, where $\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ is the Laplace operator. Does this help?

Comment: So can we identify $\varphi$ with a map $\widetilde{\varphi} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and now we are looking for it to satisfy the condition that the Laplacian of $\widetilde{\varphi}$ would be $-4$ since then $\frac{1}{4}\Delta \widetilde{\varphi} = -1$? Something as simple as $\widetilde{\varphi}(x,y) = -2x^2$ would satisfy this condition. @stange

Comment: I made an error we need $\widetilde{\varphi}(x,y) = -2x^2 + C$ where $C$ is chosen such that the function is always positive.

Comment: As we can identify $\mathbb{C}$, we can always think of a function $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $z=x+iy$. You won't find such a constant $C$, as $-2x^2\rightarrow -\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Try $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{2}\vert z \vert^2$.

Comment: For $\varphi(x+iy) = \frac{|x+iy|^2}{2} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}$ the Laplacian is $2$ so $$\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z_1} =  \frac{1}{4}\Delta \varphi = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2} \ne -1.$$ @stange

Comment: Ah, yeah, it should be $\varphi(z) = \vert z \vert^2$. As for your computation, shouldn't it be $\frac{i}{2\pi}\partial \left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \bar{z}} d \bar{z}\right) = \frac{i}{2\pi} \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial \bar{z_1}\partial z} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$, hence we need to find a  positive function such that $\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial\bar{z}\partial z} = 1$, which this $\varphi$ satisfies.

Comment: Do we not pick up the minus sign from swapping $dz$ and $d\bar{z}$? @stange

Comment: We would get an extra $-1$ from swapping, but if I'm not mistaken we don't need to swap as by definition of $\partial$ it's already in the right order

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It would seem that your initial function $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{2}\vert z \vert^2$ was indeed correct (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaehlerPotential.html) even though it wouldn't still give $1$ so I guess there is another mistake I'm making somewhere here. @stange

Comment: That depends on how people define $\omega$. As you an see here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Kähler_form, it's defined without the factor $\frac{1}{2}$, and hence $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{2}\vert z\vert^2$ would be the right choice in this case.